# How to move view from one viewController to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'm sure this is easier than I think, but I simply don't know the name, or how to search for it.

How do apps like `facebook` for example transfer a view (like an image per se) from the timeline viewController to a photoGalleryViewer type viewController so seemlessly. Often times you'll see apps use a `push` segue to between the viewControllers and you'll see the view of interest remain in the same positions as the viewControllers slide around in the back.

Here'es a quick sketch. [image]

Comment: the cleanest solution would be to create a controller containment. aka view controller container. With a custom transition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your view controller is in a UINavigationController it's possible using UINavigationControllerDelegate.

1. Set your view controller to be the delegate of your navigation controller (`self.navigationcontroller.delegate = self`)
2. Implement the method `-navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:` and return an object that conforms to the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol.
3. Implement the methods for that protocol. In the method `-animateTransition:` you will be passed a parameter that conforms to `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning`. This object will allow you to get a reference to the view controller you're transitioning to & from as well as a container view.

As with most custom animations, this isn't a trivial thing but this should get you going down the right path. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this figure:

> Navigation controller -> View Controller 1 -> View Controller 2

Add your View1 to Navigation Controller View from VC 1:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:view1];
```

Then View1 will be over VC 1 and VC 2 with no matter if you perform a push segue.